# How to prove the limit of a sequence: $\lim{\frac{n}{(n+1)^{3/2}}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to prove that $\lim{\frac{n}{(n+1)^{3/2}}}=0$. I know that I must prove this using "$\epsilon, N$" definition of the limit.

Attempt:
By definition of the limit, we need:
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. if $n \ge N$, then $|\frac{n}{(n+1)^{3/2}}|<\epsilon$.
So I need to find n as an explicit function of $\epsilon$ by simplifying inequality $|\frac{n}{(n+1)^{3/2}}|<\epsilon$.
First problem - I think I can open absolute value, but I am not sure how to justify it.
Then $\frac{n}{(n+1)^{3/2}}<\epsilon$. I do not know how to proceed further. I tried using binomial theorem (as far as I understand, special case of Taylor expansion) and got $n + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{8}{3n} - \frac{48}{3n^2} + \frac{384}{6n^3} - ... < \epsilon$ , but I do not see how it can be useful.

Comment: you can indeed show that $|\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^3}|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You know "that you must" prove it with the epsilon, N definition"? Or you **have to** ? Because it is way easier with other methods, for example the squeeze theorem

Comment: I meant I have to prove it using epsilon, it is what professor told us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the absolute values because $\frac{n}{(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ is positive when $n\geq 1$. And to make your computations easier, note that 
$$ \frac{n}{(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\frac{n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
so it's enough to choose $N$ large enough that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$.